# How to pass string value from another class file for selenium script

Tags: java, selenium

I have one class where I putting all string value.

I have another class where i have to pass that value in driver.get("")

How I can do?

Comment: Add the relevant existing code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have class A where string value kept and method that return value or you can simply make the variable public then you can access the String without mthod

```
class A
    {
       private static String a = "value to be passed";
       public static String v= "another value to be pass;"
       public static String getA(){
           return a;
    }
    }
```

Another class that required string value

```
    class ScriptTest{
       pulic void method()
    {
       driver.sendKeys(A.getA());//call the method and get the string
       driver.sendKeys(A.v);//diretly access to variable
    }
    }
```

Comment: In this scenario both class needs to be present in the same package ?

Comment: I want to pass common variable in driver.get , and other class file is not same class file , it is in different file from same package

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like,

```
Class demo1 
{
   public static String xyz = ""; 
}
```

Another `Class`, which can directly retrieve it using `extends` to `base class`,

```
class demo2 extends demo1
{
   public void testMethod()
   {
   driver.get(xyz); 
   }
}
```

This is the most preferable way for global access.